# C# Casting Int from String

Tags: c#, string, int

I'm trying to understand how I can have it so

```
string rock = 1 for inputting
string paper = 2 for input
string scissors = 3 for input
```

So i am able to use int 1,2 and 3 to print the string as output .

Basically the console application has 3 options for input: Either **1(rock)**,**2(paper)** or **3(scissors)** and the console needs to generate a random number from either 1,2 or 3 and determine if your input beats the computer random.

```
 string rock = (int)1;
        string paper;
        string scissors;
        int input;         
        Random random = new Random();
        int RandomNumber = random.Next(1,4);
        bool i = true;

        Console.WriteLine("-- Weapons Menu --");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("1] Rock");
        Console.WriteLine("2] Paper");
        Console.WriteLine("3] Scissors");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose Your Weapon [1, 2 or 3]:");

        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (input == RandomNumber ) 
            Console.WriteLine("You Tied The Computer This Round");
            Console.WriteLine("Player Chose ")
```

Any help on this would be great , thanks. I tryed to cast int but i cant .

Comment: Maybe enum solves your issue easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<int, string>`:

```
var choices = new Dictionary<int, string> { {1,"Rock"}, {2,"Paper"}, {3,"Scissors"} };
```

Then just access the correct element:

```
Console.WriteLine("Player Chose {0}", choices[input]);
```

You'll want some validation around that to make sure you don't try to access an element that doesn't exist, or that the user doesn't type in a non-numeric value.

Comment: Im liking this method , ill give it a go.

Comment: although how would I also display the computers random generation as a string ? like player Chose{0} then Computer Chose {1} ,choices,RandomNumber?

Comment: You don't need to use `string.Format` with `Console.WriteLine` since it already formats arguments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);` for castingstring to integer.
2. For Casting Int To String you have to use `input.ToString();`
3. Then you can use `Dictionary<int, string>` for achieving the goal.

And the problem in your code is in this line:  `string rock = (int)1;`
instead for this you should give `string rock = "1";`

Comment: `Console.ReaLine` returns a string, so calling `ToString` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            int RandomNumber = random.Next(1, 4);
            var userinput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Contains(Convert.ToInt16(userinput)))
                if (userinput == RandomNumber.ToString())
                    Console.WriteLine("Tied");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Check and see who won!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RockPaperScissors

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var choices = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "Rock" }, { 2, "Paper" }, { 3, "Scissors" } };
            int input;
            var randomly = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "Rock" }, { 2, "Paper" }, { 3, "Scissors" } };

            Random random = new Random();
            int RandomNumber = random.Next(1, 4);
            int Ties;
            int Wins;
            int Losses;



            do
            {
                //Counter
                Wins = 0;
                Losses = 0;
                Ties = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("-- Weapons Menu --");
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("1] Rock");
                Console.WriteLine("2] Paper");
                Console.WriteLine("3] Scissors");
                Console.WriteLine("Choose Your Weapon [1, 2 or 3]:");
                input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (input == RandomNumber)
                    Console.WriteLine("You Tied The Computer");
                Ties++;
                //Winning 
                if (input == 1 && RandomNumber == 3)

                Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");
                Wins++;

                if (input == 2 && RandomNumber == 1)

                Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");
                Wins++;

                if (input == 3 && RandomNumber == 2)

                Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");
                Wins++;


                //Lossing 
                if (input == 1 && RandomNumber == 2)

                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry You Lost To The Computer :(");
                Losses++;

                if (input == 2 && RandomNumber == 3)

                Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");
                Losses++;

                if (input == 3 && RandomNumber == 1)

                Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");
                Losses++;










                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Player Chose {0} : Computer Chose {1}", choices[input], randomly[RandomNumber]));
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("<Press Any Key To Continue...>");
                Console.WriteLine();



                Console.WriteLine("Player Wins      Computer Wins");
                Console.WriteLine("----------       --------------");
                Console.WriteLine(" {0}                {1}", Wins, Losses);




                Console.ReadKey();
                }
                while (input != 3) ;
                Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
            }enter code here
    }
    }



       STILL CANNOT SHOW THE COUNTER WHY
```